# Servlet Upload java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am trying to create a upload form using servlets, and so far i have the following;

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

    if (isMultipart) {
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        try {
            List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();

                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = item.getName();

                    String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("");
                    File path = new File(root + "/uploads");

                    if (!path.exists()) {
                        boolean status = path.mkdirs();

                    }

                    File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
                    System.out.println(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    item.write(uploadedFile);

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to upload the files fine, however it always throws a java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
Have i done something wrong?

ERROR:

```
    /Applications/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/wtpwebapps/work/uploads/texsxxdddst.xml
/Applications/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/wtpwebapps/work/uploads
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Applications/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/wtpwebapps/work/uploads (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:426)
    at servlets.uploadServlet.doPost(uploadServlet.java:48)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: Could you post some more details on the exception?

Comment: Which file throws the error? Have you checked to see what filename you're ending up with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the directory where you want to write files is write-protected, or that you don't have the rights to write there. You shouldn't write these files in this directory anyway, because it will be deleted if you undeploy or redeploy the webapp. Consider that Tomcat's directory is under Tomcat's responsibility.

Choose a directory, outside of Tomcat, where you want to store your uploads, and configure your webapp with a parameter containing this path. Use this parameter in your code to get the path and write the uploaded files.

Comment: I see, but a lot of examples i see, use something like c:/tmp, but what happens if you dont have a c:/

Comment: Well, choose another path. Have you understood my answer? The idea is to make the path configurable, by externalizing it (to a parameter in the web.xml, or a properties file, or a system property, or a setting in the database, whatever).

Comment: Yeah i get the idea, i have tried this, and ensured permissions are right yet still gives errors

Comment: mkdirs must return false, and your upload directory must thus not exist. Check that, and try to understand why it isn't created. But the easiest way is to avoid creating the directory dynamically, and create it before the app is deployed. I don't have any more precise idea. Also (but it's unrelated to the problem you have), File has a constructor wich takes a directory and a file name as arguments : new File(path, fileName).

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentation at http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItemFactory.html :

> If not otherwise configured, the default configuration values are as
>   follows:
>
> - Size threshold is 10KB.
> - Repository is the system default temp directory, as returned by System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir").

You need to be looking against `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`, not the current working directory that you're currently using.

Otherwise, and possibly preferred, use the overloaded `DiskFileItemFactory` constructor to explicitly specify where you what your files stored.

JB's answer is equally as valid.  Even if you correct what I've mentioned here, you still need to ensure that the process / user you're running the web application as has appropriate rights to whatever directory you choose.

Comment: I have used the override and have ensured i can write, yet the exception is still being given.